# session.execute() not reflected on cassandra when done on spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am running a spark job where some data is loaded from cassandra table. From that data, I make some insert and delete statements.
and execute them. *(using forEach)*

```
boolean deleteStatus= connector.openSession().execute(delete).wasApplied();
boolean  insertStatus = connector.openSession().execute(insert).wasApplied();
System.out.println(delete+":"+deleteStatus);
System.out.println(insert+":"+insertStatus);
```

When i run it locally, i see the respective results in the table.
However, when I run it on a cluster, sometimes the result is displayed and sometime the changes don't take place.
I saw the stdout from web-ui of spark, and the query along with true was printed for both the queries.*(Data was loaded correctly. But sometimes, only insert is reflected, sometimes only delete, sometimes both, and most of the times none.)*

Specifications:

1. spark slaves on same machines as the cassandra nodes.(each node has two instances of slaves.)
2. spark master on a separate machine.
3. Repair done on all nodes.
4. Cassandra restarted

Answer (score 0):

> boolean deleteStatus= connector.openSession().execute(delete).wasApplied();
>
> boolean  insertStatus = connector.openSession().execute(insert).wasApplied();

This is a known **anti-pattern**, you create a new Session object for each query, which is extremely expensive.

Just create the session once and re-use it for all the queries.

To see which queries are being executed and sent to Cassandra, use the slow query logger feature as a hack: http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/logging/#logging-query-latencies

The idea is to set the threshold to a ridiculously low value so that every query will be considered slow and displayed in the log.

**You should use this hack only for testing of course**

Comment: It is done only for testing purpose. 
Actually a session is opened per partition, (forEachPartition) and then (forEachRemaining) on Iterator<CassandraRow>